# TensorFlow / PyTorch: Gradient for loss which is measured externally

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, pytorch, gradient, backpropagation

I am relatively new to Machine Learning and Python.

I have a system, which consists of a NN whose output is fed into an unknown nonlinear function F, e.g. some hardware. The idea is to train the NN to be an inverse F^(-1) of that unknown nonlinear function F. This means that a loss L is calculated at the output of F. However, backpropagation cannot be used in a straightforward manner for calculating the gradients and updating the NN weights because the gradient of F is not known either.

Is there any way how to use a loss function L, which is not directly connected to the NN, for the calculation of the gradients in TensorFlow or PyTorch? Or to take a loss that was obtained with any other software (Matlab, C, etc.) use it for backpropagation?

- As far as I know, Keras keras.backend.gradients only allows to calculate gradients with respect to connected weights, otherwise the gradient is either zero or NoneType.
- I read about the stop_gradient() function in TensorFlow. But I am not sure whether this is what I am looking for. It allows to not compute the gradient with respect to some variables during backpropagation. But I think the operation F is not interpreted as a variable anyway.
- Can I define any arbitrary loss function (including a hardware measurement) and use it for backpropagation in TensorFlow or is it required to be connected to the graph as well?

Please, let me know if my question is not specific enough.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, all modern deep learning packages ([pytorch](/questions/tagged/pytorch), [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow), [keras](/questions/tagged/keras) etc.) are relaying on [gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) (and its many variants) to train networks.
As the name suggests, you **cannot** do gradient descent without gradients.

However, you might circumvent the "non differentiability" of your "given" function `F` by looking at the problem from a slightly different perspective:
You are trying to learn a model `M` that "counters" the effect of `F`. So you have access to `F` (but not its gradients) and a set of representative inputs `X={x_0, x_1, ... x_n}`.
For each example `x_i` you can compute `y_i = F(x_i)` and your end goal is to have a model `M` that given `y_i` will output `x_i`.
Therefore, you can treat `y_i` as your model's input and compute a loss between `M(y_i)` and `x_i` that produced it. This way you do not need to compute gradients through the "black box" `F`.

A pseudo code would look something like:

```py
for x in examples:
  y = F(x)  # applying F on x - getting only output WITHOUT any gradients
  pred = M(y)  # apply the trainable model M to the output of F
  loss = ||x - pred||  # loss will propagate gradients through M and stop at F
  loss.backward()
```

Comment: Your suggestion works and I implemented that already, but it has a drawback limiting its accuracy. What you propose is to put a NN at the output of F, i.e, using y as input and x as label. However, in my system I need the NN in front of the unknown function F and not after it for different reasons. If I train the NN as in your pseudo code and put it in front of F afterwards, I am swapping the order of nonlinear elements, which decreases the system performance if M is not exactly the inverse of F due to the non-commutative property for nonlinear operators.